# Ljung-Box test in R - unexpected results

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, correlation

I am studying the property of a simulated time series z_t. In brief, `z_t` is generated as follows: `y_t` is an `AR(1)` process with innovations `e_t`; `z_t` is `y_t * e_t`. I expect `z_t` to show lag-1 correlation.

I performed the Ljung-Box test for `z_t` in R and found that my result depends a lot on the seed value (for certain seeds I get p-value < 0.001, for others I get p-value near 1; I tested 10 seeds). I also tried to compute the p-value explicitly based on a possible definition of the LB test and found that it's always small. The same analysis done in Python provides low p-values. I suspect that I may be using the `Box.test()` function incorrectly.

Here is some code to reproduce the problem; the last 3 lines are for my hands-on LB test:

```
n <- 1000; phi = 0.9; set.seed(9)
errors <- rnorm(n); Y <- rep(0, times <- n)

for (k in 2:1000){
    Y[k] <- phi * Y[k-1] + errors[k]
}
y <- ts(Y)

z <- y * errors
Box.test(z, lag=1, type="Ljung-Box", fitdf = 0) 
# note: result doesn't depend very much on number of lags
# sometimes result > 0.1.

r1 <- sum(z*lag(z,-1)) / sum(z**2) #1st order autocorrelation
LB <- n * ((n+2)/(n-1))*r1**2      #LB statistic for lag = 1.
1 - pchisq(LB, 1) # p-value of the LB test; always << 1.
```

Comment: Why should be suspicious that results depend on the seed?

Comment: It's suspicious that the series z_t is very strongly correlated (p < 0.001) 20% of the time and not correlated at all (p > 0.1) in the other cases. This only happens in R. When I do the same thing in Python, it is always correlated.